# How to label some properties into graph like labeling EdgeWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

We can label the `EdgeWeight` into edge like following

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> Range@3, 
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]

But how to label the `EdgeCapacity` , `EdgeCost` and `VertexCapacity` into graph with an ease solution?

Comment: Title and body do not match.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry.I make a mistake.

Comment: Same problem to me. I simply do not understand why this does not work. I a flow graph `EdgeCapacity`would be appropriate.

Comment: related q/a: [Label graphs based on custom properties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133951/125)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a `graph` with `EdgeCapacity`

```
graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeCapacity -> Range@3];
```

we have a in-build method

```
Graph[graph, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Thread[EdgeList[
     graph] -> (PropertyValue[{graph, #}, EdgeCapacity] & /@ 
      EdgeList[graph])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

And there is a coming method based on [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM)

```
IGEdgeMap[# &, EdgeLabels -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeCapacity], graph]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]